# Check value of span inside a div using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check if the  value inside my div is not empty so I can hide the "header" div. But my javascript is failing.

Note: span should not have id, only the div.

```
 <div id="header">
      <label>This is a header</label>
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <label>My Label</label>
        <span>Dog</span>    
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 function hideHeaders(){

var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var x = roadDiv.getElementsByTagName('span');

if(x.value == ""){ 
   document.getElementById('header').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: x will most likely be an array, try `x[0].nodeValue`

Comment: excuse me `x[0].textContent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of corrections need to happen in your code. First, `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` so you need to access each individual item by index like

```
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
```

Also, `roadDiv` is undefined and you should use `document` or a parent container for above.

Next, for `span` elements you need to use `innerHTML`, not `value`

```
if (x.innerHTML == "") {
```

```js
function hideHeaders() {

  var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];

  if (x.innerHTML == "") {
    document.getElementById('header').style.display = "none";
  }
}
hideHeaders();
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <label>This is a header</label>
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
  <label>My Label</label>
  <span></span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would also be better to use === instead of ==, not that it would make much difference for this block but just to element any issues with your code style in future and eliminate running into any strange bugs by two arguments being equal but of a different type.